# Unable to get VS2010 to connect to remote debugger on Windows 8 PC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, remote-debugging

I have a Win 7 64 bit PC running VS2010
I have one test machine that is generating issues for me (a Win 8 one), but I cannot connect to it via Remote Debugger.

To complicate issues, this remote machine is a VM hosted via Paralells.

I have turned off all firewalls (I don't like this, but that makes the server appear in the VS2010 window, so I know I need to come back and tweak the firewall.)

I go to the remote machine, start up vsmon (I have tried both x86 and 64 versions), and the server starts ok.
try to connect and I get "MSVSMON.exe does not appear to be running on the remote instance." (Even though I know it is as I just started it!)

I have gone into settings and enabled "Any User" and "No Authentication". Restarted VS2010 and still nothign. Exactly the same error message.

I have a User called Matt on both the Win 7 and Win 8 machines, both with admin rights to the resepctive boxes. But still the same error message.

So what steps have I missed?

(and as a supplemental, I am sure that in teh documentaiton for the remote debug server download, it states that the install will create the necessary firewall rules, so why is my firewall still blocking me seeing the Win 8 Machine?)

Im out of ideas on this one, so if I can't crack this soon I'll have to move my dev envrionment across to the win 8 vm lock stock and barrel, which then means that my test machine is no longer an exact replica of a client workstation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy directory `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\` to the remote computer.
2. Start x64 version of `msvsmon.exe` as user Matt.  Do not enable "Any User" or "No Authentication". User Matt should have administrator rights.
3. Start your visual studio 2010 as Matt.
4. Try to connect to remote debugger. It worked for me every time. If it does not, consider using higher version of visual studio (i.e. vs 2013 community edition is free and should work well).